# Why do standardscaler and normalizer need different data input?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, normalization, scaling

I was trying the following code and found that `StandardScaler(or MinMaxScaler)` and `Normalizer` from `sklearn` handle data very differently. This issue makes the pipeline construction more difficult. I was wondering if this design discrepancy is intentional or not.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, Normalizer, MinMaxScaler
```

For `Normalizer`, the data is read "horizontally".

```
Normalizer(norm = 'max').fit_transform([[ 1., 1.,  2., 10],
                                        [ 2.,  0.,  0., 100],
                                        [ 0.,  -1., -1., 1000]])
#array([[ 0.1  ,  0.1  ,  0.2  ,  1.   ],
#       [ 0.02 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  1.   ],
#       [ 0.   , -0.001, -0.001,  1.   ]])
```

For `StandardScaler` and `MinMaxScaler`, the data is read "vertically".

```
StandardScaler().fit_transform([[ 1., 1.,  2., 10],
                                [ 2.,  0.,  0., 100],
                                [ 0.,  -1., -1., 1000]])
#array([[ 0.        ,  1.22474487,  1.33630621, -0.80538727],
#       [ 1.22474487,  0.        , -0.26726124, -0.60404045],
#       [-1.22474487, -1.22474487, -1.06904497,  1.40942772]])

MinMaxScaler().fit_transform([[ 1., 1.,  2., 10],
                              [ 2.,  0.,  0., 100],
                              [ 0.,  -1., -1., 1000]])
#array([[0.5       , 1.        , 1.        , 0.        ],
#       [1.        , 0.5       , 0.33333333, 0.09090909],
#       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior, because `StandardScaler` and `Normalizer` serve different purposes. The [`StandardScaler`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) works 'vertically', because it...

> Standardize[s] features by removing the mean and scaling to unit variance
>
> [...]
>   Centering and scaling happen independently on each feature by computing the relevant statistics on the samples in the training set. Mean and standard deviation are then stored to be used on later data using the transform method.

while the [`Normalizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer) works 'horizontally', because it...

> Normalize[s] samples individually to unit norm.
>
> Each sample (i.e. each row of the data matrix) with at least one non zero component is rescaled independently of other samples so that its norm (l1 or l2) equals one.

Please have a look at the scikit-learn docs (links above), to get more insight, which serves your purpose better.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I was very confused because the term "normalization" was used very liberally in a lot of cases. Some articles call MinMaxScaler normalization. Your answer was really helpful!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Please consider upvoting and accepting my answer to give me credit.