# TensorFlow per_image_standardization vs mean standardization across full dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am curious about the difference between standardizing each image individually vs standardizing across the full data set.

I am using [tensorflow/models/official/resnet](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/official/resnet) which is built using tf.estimator.  The tf estimator supports an input pipeline function that produces a tf Dataset.  The Dataset object applies the [tf.image.per_image_standardization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/per_image_standardization) op that standardizes by subtracting the mean of the image itself from each pixel and enforces unit variance.

This is different from other ML preprocessing that standardizes the image based on the mean across the whole dataset, such as with [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

I'm confused as to whether any aspect of this input pipeline is persisted in the tf SavedModel exported from the tf.estimator.Estimator.

So I'm wondering if I need to still apply feature standardization when serving the model, either via tf.contrib.predictor or when deploying the model in any other dnn format.

Should I be applying standardization across the dataset even though I'm using the per_image_standardization?  If so, should I just export the mean value from the whole image set somehow so that when serving the model the server can just pick up the mean value from the whole dataset and apply standardization that way?

Comment: `StandardScaler`-type is not the only option; see the nice recent answer at [Why do standardscaler and normalizer need different data input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54115571/why-do-standardscaler-and-normalizer-need-different-data-input).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In StandardScaler, we do feature-wise normalization. In case of images, we can do pixel-wise normalization, by considering the entire data-distribution, but that is not helpful, because of variability in the distribution. So **per_image_standardization** is preferred, which normalize the entire image to mean zero and std 1. **It also make learning fast.**

Further [this-link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211436/why-normalize-images-by-subtracting-datasets-image-mean-instead-of-the-current) can be helpful. There is [another-link](https://becominghuman.ai/image-data-pre-processing-for-neural-networks-498289068258), where author has explained this by taking an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I find myself a little confused about how to use the same operation provided by per_image_standardization at serve-time.  For instance, I am building a tf.Estimator, which has an input_fn that provides a tf.Dataset, upon which I apply map_and_batch which calls per_image_standardization.  This returns a tensor.  But when I export the model, the same tensor isn't exported, because the input pipeline is absent.  Should I add per_image_standardization to the model_fn instead?  If I do so, can this operation still be converted to caffe as part of the compute graph?